# Best (most security conscious) way to package a MSSQL database for 3rd party use?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, mysql

It has been requested of me to dump an entire database hosted on MS SQL Server 2005 with multiple tables for a third party to then import/use.

- My first thought was to find something like mysqld_dump that would give them import commands, which lead me to the "generate scripts" with schema and data, which should work.

  - one concern with this option is data that has primary/foreign key requirements, does the script it creates keep this in mind, should it be no problem? I am doing a test import now to attempt to verify this; thought I would mention it.

---

- It was suggested for quicker resolution to just dismount the database and give them the MDF file. I am not sure I like this idea, as I am not so familiar with everything that gets stored in this file. Is it a security risk to our server at all? is there references stored in this file that specifically relate to our server that may allow for damages?

My main concern is security here, as long as they get the data everyone will be happy.

Any advise or even better alternatives that i have not thought of would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do they just need the data? Why not just export it to Excel?

Comment: currently we are looking for a solution that includes the ability for them to use it within SQL without too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just backup and restore the database to a server that the 3rd party has access to, or deploy it on a server for them and restrict their access and only give them ability to run scripts and other basic permissions?

Comment: we want to avoid prolonging the service of hosting this data for them; the reason for packaging it up is so that we can part ways.

Comment: as for backup/restore, which functionality are you specifically referring too? and what are the security implications?

Comment: By backup/restore I meant right click on the database in the object explorer (SQL Server Management Studio), then Tasks, then Backup, the option for Restore is there too. If I was you, I'd just remove all the roles & permissions, keep the default sa account and give it a password that you can tell the third party, backup (like I said how to above), then they can restore it. No security implications as you've taken all your role/permission information out of it anyway :)

Comment: so the permissions tab of the database properties is the only area i should be worried about clearing correct? this would be included in the backup? this is looking like the best and easiest solution.

Comment: All of the security will be packaged in it, you're best off clearing it all out, but before you do so change the sa password to something you'll remember and make sure it's dbowner on that database, then you can delete the rest of the roles/logins

Comment: currently the roles/permissions area is blank actually the permissions are on the server as all sources are only accessed by us internally, but the db owner is a windows user. id like to avoid messing with the sa user's password, could i just create a dummy windows user to assign ownership too, would they have to use the same username and know the password to be able to restore it?

Comment: You're probably best off just using SQL Server Authentication then and creating a dummy SQL user and give it dbowner. If you used a windows user they'd have to be signed into windows as that windows user, meaning they'd have to create the user at their end (assuming you're not on the same network of course)